# How do I trigger a script to re-run every time there is a kernel upgrade?

Tags: kernel, package-management

Say, for example, I have a custom kernel module.

Is there a way to trigger a rebuild on every kernel upgrade in a generic way such that I can perform an arbitrary task (recompile the kernel module) on every kernel upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the man page for kernel-img.conf
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man5/kernel-img.conf.5.html
The postinst_hook keyword identifies a script you can select to run at installation.  Other keys select other times to run scripts, like at removal.

Comment: I appreciate the direction to a particular man page, but a worthwhile of accepting answer has an example.  (the other answer provides a dated one).  If I don't get an answer with an example, I'll post my use case as a self answer and accept it.  Just a warning (I'ld like to accept someone else's answer).